# Как в Windows получить доступ к запущенной консоли?

Tags: windows, cmd

На Windows Server установлен OpenSSH. Из Linux подключаюсь к серверу и запускаю программу, которая создает cmd окно. Как в это окно отправить команду из cmd (к которому через SSH подключен)